# PHP compare boolean values

Tags: php

I want to compare strings in an multi dimensional PHP ARRAY
I ran the Debugger and it jumps into the if condition but in my opinion it should not.

```
$strEmpty = $this->areStringsEmpty($needle, $haystack[$i]); // FALSE after method call

$one=strcasecmp($haystack[$i][0],$needle[0]); // evaluates to 6 , which shoult be FALSE
$two=strcasecmp($haystack[$i][1], $needle[1]); //evaluates to 2 , which alse should be false

if (!$strEmpty && $one && $two) { // TRUE && FALSE && FALSE
    return TRUE;
}
```

why is this so ?
I know i could check against 0 in the condition , but i am wondering why this isnt done automatically.

Comment: '6 which should be false'. It isn't, in PHP.

Comment: It would help if you gave use some sample input values that you think should evaluate to `true` or `false`. Your expectations might be different from the rest of ours.

Comment: What you should be aware of is that 'strcasecmp' is returning 0 when the strings are identical, and a signed integer otherwise. That direct boolean comparison on integer values is perhaps the source of your confusion.

Comment: How can i get boolean values from the strcasecmp function or is this not possible?

Comment: @user3741086 Do you want it to be `true` or `false` when the strings are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, `strcasecmp` returns numbers. So it'll be `true` if the return is greater or lower than 0.

Input:

```
$var1 = "Hello";
$var2 = "hello2";
if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == true) {
    var_dump(strcasecmp($var1, $var2));
}
```

Output:

```
int(-1)
```

As you can see, it's -1, but it's true.

You could simply add braces around the `strcasecmp`.

```
$one = (strcasecmp($haystack[$i][0], $needle[0]) == 0);
$two = (strcasecmp($haystack[$i][1], $needle[1]) == 0);
```

This will give you true if it's equal, false if it's not.

[Example](http://ideone.com/xVieRA)

Answer (score 2):

`strcasecmp` returns 0 when the string matches. To get a boolean `true` when the strings match, you can do this.

```
    $one=(strcasecmp($haystack[$i][0],$needle[0]) === 0); //TRUE when === 0
    $two=(strcasecmp($haystack[$i][1], $needle[1]) === 0);  //TRUE when === 0
```